# How many logical replication connecttions will I have?

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, logical-replication

Does each publisher and subscriber in PostgreSQL logical replication require a separate connection?
I want to publish some tables partially and some fully and was wondering how many connections do I need to reserve per table on the publisher and subscriber instance with PostgreSQL.

I have read the documentation, and these things are still not 100% clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be one connection for each enabled subscription.